# Calculate mean for column grouped by values of two other columns

Tags: r, group-by

I have a dataframe with 5 columns. I know how to calculate the mean for one column grouped by another column. However, i need to group it by two columns. For example, I want to calculate the mean for column 5 grouped by column 1 and column 2.

```
df <- structure(list(Country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AT", "CH", "DE"), class = "factor"), 
    Occupation = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L), 
    Age = c(20L, 46L, 30L, 12L, 73L, 53L, 19L, 43L, 65L, 53L, 
    19L, 34L, 76L, 25L, 45L, 39L, 18L, 59L, 37L, 24L, 19L, 60L, 
    51L, 32L, 29L), Gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor"), 
    Income = c(100L, 80L, 78L, 29L, 156L, 56L, 95L, 104L, 87L, 
    56L, 203L, 45L, 112L, 78L, 56L, 140L, 99L, 67L, 89L, 109L, 
    43L, 145L, 30L, 101L, 77L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))

head(df)

  Country Occupation Age Gender Income
1      AT          1  20 female    100
2      AT          3  46 female     80
3      AT          5  30   male     78
4      AT          3  12   male     29
5      AT          1  73   male    156
6      AT          2  53 female     56
```

So what I want to to is calculate the mean for column ‘income’, grouped by country and occupation. E.g., I want to calculate the mean of ‘income’ for all those people living in country ‘AT’ with occupation ‘3’, the mean of ‘income’ for all those living in country ‘CH’ with occupation ‘1’ and so on.

Comment: Show us how you would do the mean conditional on one column... and surely that can be extended easily to two columns. What is your expected output? another `data.frame`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**(1) base method (aggregate)**

```
mean.df <- aggregate(Income ~ Country + Occupation, df, mean)
names(mean.df)[3] <- "Income_Mean"
merge(df, mean.df)
```

**(2) base method (tapply)**

```
mean.df1 <- tapply(df$Income, list(df$Country, df$Occupation), mean)
mean.df2 <- as.data.frame(as.table(mean.df1))
names(mean.df2) <- c("Country", "Occupation", "Income_Mean")
merge(df, mean.df2)
```

**(3) stats method (ave)**

```
df2 <- df
df2$Income_Mean <- ave(df$Income, df$Country, df$Occupation)
```

**(4) dplyr method**

```
df %>% group_by(Country, Occupation) %>%
       mutate(Income_Mean = mean(Income))
```

---

**Output :**

```
   Country Occupation   Age Gender Income Income_Mean
   <fct>        <int> <int> <fct>   <int>       <dbl>
 1 AT               1    20 female    100       128  
 2 AT               3    46 female     80        71  
 3 AT               5    30 male       78        86.5
 4 AT               3    12 male       29        71  
 5 AT               1    73 male      156       128  
 6 AT               2    53 female     56        56  
 7 AT               5    19 male       95        86.5
 8 AT               3    43 male      104        71  
 9 CH               5    65 male       87        82.5
10 CH               3    53 female     56        84
# ... with 15 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! Now, I have another question if you could help me please. I want to add the means as a variable to my existing data frame. This means all people in my data frame who are from AT with occupation 1 should have mean 128, all from AT with occupation 3 should have mean 71 and so on. Do you know how i can assign the corresponding means to each group?

Comment: @SeanBurgess see the edit. I revise all versions.

Comment: Thanks you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `sqldf`:

```
sqldf("select Country,Occupation,Age,Gender,avg(Income) from df group by Country,Occupation")
```

**OR**

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
df=data.table(df)
df[, mean(Income), by = list(Country,Occupation)]
```

Output:

```
    Country Occupation Age Gender avg(Income)
1       AT          1  73   male       128.0
2       AT          2  53 female        56.0
3       AT          3  43   male        71.0
4       AT          5  19   male        86.5
5       CH          1  18 female       138.0
6       CH          2  34   male        45.0
7       CH          3  39   male        84.0
8       CH          5  25 female        82.5
9       DE          1  32 female       123.0
10      DE          2  51 female        59.5
11      DE          3  29   male        72.0
12      DE          5  19   male        76.0
```